# Struggling to produce queries

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
Produce a list of films which have a date of release before August 2016.
```

Hello trying to produce the following SQL query above with this:

> SELECT *
>       FROM FILM
>       WHERE DATE_OF_RELEASE < '2016-08-01';

but I cannot seem to figure out why I am getting errors?

---

Trying to answer this as well: **Write a SQL statement to count the number of films in the database released before August 2016.**

> SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Number of films released before August 2016 "
>   FROM FILM;
>   WHERE date_of_release < date '2016-08-01';

however get this error:

Error starting at line : 18 in command -
WHERE date_of_release < date '2016-08-01'
Error report -
Unknown Command

Comment: The first query is missing its `date` keyword. The second query has a stray `;` after `FILM`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it the wrong way - do it the **right** way.

If `DATE_OF_RELEASE` column's datatype is `DATE` (it should be), then compare it to `DATE`, not a string. `'01-aug-16'` or `'2016-08-01'` are **strings**, not dates. Don't rely on Oracle and its capabilities to implicitly convert them to dates, because sooner or later it'll fail, as soon as NLS settings change.

So, use

```
where date_of_release < date '2016-08-01'   -- date literal
```

or

```
where date_of_release < to_date('01.08.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy') -- TO_DATE function
```

Leave strings alone.

Comment: @PetruMaika . . . The correct way is the `date` keyword.  Learn to use it!

Comment: Trying to do something similar for this question: Write a SQL statement to count the number of films in the database released before August 2016.  

SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Number of films released before August 2016 "
FROM FILM;
WHERE date_of_release < date '2016-08-01';

However get this error:

Error starting at line : 18 in command -
WHERE date_of_release < date '2016-08-01'
Error report -
Unknown Command

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM FILM WHERE DATE_OF_RELEASE < '01-AUG-16';
```

Comment: yeah realised this literally 5 mins after I posted. Thank-you!

Comment: This may or may not work depending on your NLS settings. You should really write standard date literals instead of typing whatever seems convenient and hoping for the best.